# Degeneracy in molecular rotation energy levels for asymmetric molecules

Tags: rotational-dynamics, schroedinger-equation

I was recently reading Atkins' Physical Chemistry, the topic of rotational energies of molecules.  It states the degeneracies of spherical top, symmetric and linear molecules as being $(2J+1)^2$, $2(2J+1)$ and $(2J+1)$, respectively ($J$ being the rotational quantum number).

Atkins however does not discuss about asymmetric non-linear molecules. I would like to know the degeneracy for each energy level for asymmetric tops. Is it $1$, or $J$ or $(2J+1)$?  Please let me know. If I assume $(2J+1)$ to be the degeneracy, I was working with ethylene molecule which is an asymmetric top with rotational constants $147$, $25$, $30$ GHz (A, B, C). So, rotational energy along "A-axis" for quantum number $J$ is $AJ(J+1)h$, if I take the degeneracy to be $(2J+1)$ along the "A-axis", the mean energy of rotation (from the dependence on partition function, Atkins 9th edition Chapter 16) comes out to be (at high temperature limit) kT.

Similarly, adding the mean energies for each axes A, B, C, the total rotational mean energy is $3kT$, while I was expecting it to be $1.5kT$ ($0.5kT$ for each axis - from quadratic contribition $\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$).

May be I am mistaken somewhere can please help me?

Comment: In the approximation of the separation of rotation and vibration, the asymmetric top energies are indeed $2J+1$-degenerate. The convention for the $A$, $B$, and $C$ constants is for them to be in decreasing energy, so you should flip the 25 and 30 GHz, but that's just a minor point. I don't know off the top of my head how the stat mech should work, so I'll wait for someone with better knowledge to answer that part.